# Why can this model predict the rotation of MNIST digits that accurately?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mnist

I've trained a model on the MNIST set in order to detect the rotation (0, 90, 180, 270 degrees) of the digits like so:

```
# model / data parameters
num_classes = 4
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

# load the data and split it between train and test sets
(x_train_orig, _), (x_test_orig, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# generate new data set with rotated numbers
x_train = []
y_train = []
for img in x_train_orig:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        x_train.append(np.rot90(img, i))
        y_train.append(i)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

x_test = []
y_test = []
for img in x_test_orig:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        x_test.append(np.rot90(img, i))
        y_test.append(i)
x_test = np.array(x_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

# scale images to the [0, 1] range
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
# make sure images have shape (28, 28, 1)
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ])

batch_size = 128
epochs = 10

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

save_model(model, os.path.join('model', 'saved_numori_model'))
```

I am then running a check on the test set with "1"'s rotated 270 degrees using the following code:

```
model_ori = load_model(os.path.join('model', 'saved_numori_model'), compile=True)
(_, _), (x_test_orig, y_test_orig) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_test_orig = x_test_orig.astype("float32") / 255

subimages = []
rot = 3
while len(subimages) < 8:
    rnd = np.random.randint(0, x_test_orig.shape[0])
    if y_test_orig[rnd] != 1:
        continue
    subimage = x_test_orig[rnd]
    subimages.append(np.rot90(subimage, rot))

subimages = np.array(subimages)

_, ax = plt.subplots(1, subimages.shape[0])
for i in range(subimages.shape[0]):
    ax[i].imshow(subimages[i])
    ax[i].axis('off')
plt.show()

predictions_ori = model_ori.predict(np.expand_dims(subimages, -1), verbose=verbose)
print("Probabilities for orientation:")
for prediction in predictions_ori:
    for i, probability in enumerate(prediction):
        print(f"{i}: {probability:.02f}    ", end="")
    print(f"Prediction: {np.argmax(prediction)}")
```

This results in the following output for "1"'s:

[image]

And for "0"'s:

[image]

I simply cannot understand why it can predict those rotations that accurately. What I was expecting was a high uncertainty between rotation of 90 or 270 degrees for the "1"'s and the "0"'s.

Why can the model prediction those rotations that accurately? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It would just be possible to classify them by small differences like angle, bend, thickness, etc. And if it is possible, the model will not show any uncertainty because you have not trained it to do so. Note that even if the model thinks it is 50-50, it is allowed to output 1.0 (unlikely, but allowed).

Comment: @ken How could I change to model to allow/report uncertainty?

Comment: The question is, why do you want it? If you want "90 and 270 to always be uncertain", then just merge the 90 and 270 classes into a single class that represents "90 or 270".

Comment: @ken I'm actually trying to detect numbers that are rotated (90,180, 270). But since I get very unreliable results with my own testdata, the above came up while trying to debug it. It seems weird to me that it is working that good with the MNIST test set but basically not at all with my own numbers.

Comment: Have you tried with other digits?

Comment: @rr_goyal Sure, I've tried them all but unfortunately without success.